# how to assign customer id from php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to send an order to a database. I created a form for the customer to fill his details and then on submit i have a query which sends the details of the customer to the database. I also have another query which sends the items in cart in a link table. The link table links the customer with the products.

---

The problem is on my second query I am not able reference the customer with his id because the customer its not store in the system yet. the customer id is auto created in msql with the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) on how to do this. You want to use `mysqli_insert_id` (Or it's Object oriented counterpart) to get the last inserted ID in the database (If your database is using auto incremented keys), and use that in your second query.

Have a look at this sample:

```
<?php

$order_item = 'test_item';

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "INSERT INTO customers VALUES (NULL, 'first_name', 'last_name')";
$mysqli->query($query);

$newid = $mysqli->insert_id;

printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $newid);


if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO orders VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)")) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $newid, $order_item);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly I think there's a solution. It would be a lot better if you could post some code along with the question.

You can detect the most recent query sent to the second table using

```
SELECT `customer_id` from `orders` order by DESC limit 1;
```

You should then be able to use php to +1 that to retrieve like:

```
$newid = $mostrecentid + 1;
```

This would then give you the most recent id which you can use for your second query